# Multiple redirects / rewrites within one VirtualHost group

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a client that now wants to point a couple of dozen urls to their main site. I have added them as serveralias's in the sites apache config file... so now all of these urls point to the primary one... excellent.

The problem i have is that if ANY of these alias's are accessed at the root (i.e. www.domain.com rather than www.domain.com/some-page/) then i need to redirect them to a specific page within the site (i.e. anyone accessing domain.com might need to be sent to domain.com/special-landing-page/). However, any visit to anything other than the landing page should just continue as normal without any re-directs.

I've been battling with this for a few hours and can't seem to find the best solution. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:
Ah i was actually doing that.. but couldnt get it to work. Any comments:

ServerName m-g-i.co.uk
    ServerAlias m-g-i.co.uk *.m-g-i.co.uk
        ServerAlias central-heating-nottingham.co.uk *.central-heating-nottingham.co.uk

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?central-heating-nottingham.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ /nottingham [R,L]

DocumentRoot /home/ben/sites/mgi/releases/current/mgi

    WSGIScriptAlias and other WSGI stuff....
```

Update:
I am getting the following output in the log...

I am getting the following output:

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2010:22:07:50 +0100] [m-g-i.co.uk/sid#84464a8][rid#8711c60/subreq] (1) pass through /

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2010:22:07:56 +0100] [m-g-i.co.uk/sid#84464a8][rid#870dc50/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2010:22:07:56 +0100] [m-g-i.co.uk/sid#84464a8][rid#870dc50/initial] (3) applying pattern '^$' to uri '/favicon.ico'

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2010:22:07:56 +0100] [m-g-i.co.uk/sid#84464a8][rid#870dc50/initial] (1) pass through /favicon.ico

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2010:22:07:56 +0100] [m-g-i.co.uk/sid#84464a8][rid#8713c68/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /favicon.ico

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /special-landing-page [R,L]
```

post what you've tried.

Use the following in the config file to generate a rewrite log to see just what is happening

```
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog /tmp/rl
```

Disable this afterwards as it can be quite server intensive on a busy site.

Comment: any particular reason you can't just use separate VirtualHost configs for each domain?  

Not enough of that log to see what isn't working.  Can you snip the logs from a failed redirect?  Should favicon have also been rewritten?

Comment: I can add them to seperate virtualhost configs, and i'd happily do that but would that mean that i would have to create a seperate wsgi process for each one or is there a way to share across all domains? Secondly, i would still have the issue that if accessing the url root i need to redirect the user to a particular sub-path. 

I'm really stuck on this :(